# If any cell getting data in column then print complete row

Tags: spreadsheet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiSIL.jpg)Here i am trying to create a new table from this existing table with skipping empty column or row.

In existing table department row can be increase or decrease because its getting unique velue from database, as same as with project column getting velue from database also it can be increase or decrease. I want to create a new table which if department row getting any department name then print complete column.